# Error message in Android Studio emulator when integrating Parse

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-emulator

I'm having an issue with Android Studio. I am using Parse and have added my application and client keys. But when using an emulator I am receiving this message. Does anyone know the possible issue?

```
01-30 10:27:40.466    1100-1100/ex.co.uk.ex E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ex.co.uk.ex, PID: 1100
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bolts.Task
        at com.parse.ParseInstallation.hasCurrentInstallationAsync(ParseInstallation.java:90)
        at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.updateAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:96)
        at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:163)
        at ex.co.uk.ex.ParseApplication.onCreate(ParseApplication.java:17)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your app gradle file in the dependencies part. Then Sync and Build & Run again.

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
```